how can I convert the 'string' from arrayBuffer to arrayBuffer again?
const filePath = path.join(pdfFolderPath, file);

// Read the PDF file
const fileData = await fs.readFile(filePath);

// Load the PDF document
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(fileData);
const arrayBuffer = await pdfDoc.save(); // Save as ArrayBuffer

// Get the file name without extension
const nameWithoutExtension = path.basename(file, path.extname(file));

// Convert to Base64 string for JSON
pdfArray.push({
  name: nameWithoutExtension, // Save without .pdf
  pdf: arrayBuffer.toString("base64"),
});

I have that pdf value as arrayBuffer.toString("base64").
const a = await pdfSearch(`${output[i]["field4"]}`, arrivalPdf);

// const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer(); // Get the PDF as an ArrayBuffer
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(a.pdf);

a.pdf is the string value that I get from converted value. I've been trying to convert it back to feed it to PDFDocument.load(). Stuck for like 3 days. Tried 10 different things that I could find here.
I know that this is very redundant question but I could not work it out after trying different stackoverflow solutions again and again :/
how can I change it to something that I can load it to PDFDocument.load() from pdf-lib?
I tried with atob but it did not work. Also, I am trying to do this on a browser without fetching anything. No server. Just from a plain html. I think I can use the package but many did not work too.
That I saved base64 string - which works fine if I convert to PDF arraybuffer.

This is the String   pdf: arrayBuffer.toString("base64"), that I have a hard time converting to.


Double check if arrayBuffer.toString("base64") is doing what you expect.

Firstly, to get base64 of the file, you'd want Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).toString("base64"), since arrayBuffer.toString() is NOT what you think it is - standard (i.e in browsers) arrayBuffer.toString() outputs "[object ArrayBuffer]"

I've attached the two different json that does work and doesn't work. Because I am limited to .string(). I dunno what to do.
